# Export Data As CSV In CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I need to export results from a MySQL query into a csv file in codeigniter.

This is the model:

```
public function export_csv()
{

       $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $delimiter = ",";
    $newline = "\r\n";
    $file_name = 'BVN_REPORTS'.date("Y-m-d h-i-s").'.csv';
    $query = 'SELECT  account_name as "Account Name",
    api_account_name as "Verified Name", 
    account_num "Account Number", 
    bvn "Bank Verification Number (BVN)", bank_name as "BANK NAME" 
    from ew_employees where bvn is not null
    ORDER BY bank_name ';
   $result = $this->db->query($query);
   $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($result, $delimiter, $newline);
   if(force_download($filename, $data)){
   echo 'Done';
   }
   else {echo 'Not Done';}
    }
```

And this is the controller:

```
  public function get_csv()
{
     $this->load->model('employees_model');
     $this->employees_model->export_csv();
}
```

The result is always 'Not Done'...how can i force a csv download of the query results.Thanks

Comment: Are you sure file is loaded ??

Comment: The file is supposed to be created dynamically and populated with the query results

Comment: Check manually file is created or not

Comment: The code is supposed to create the file...it is not in existence yet

Comment: check file permissions

Answer (score 2):

According to the Question title let me Answer the question.Generally it may help other when visit here.
what i generally do when exporting data to csv.

```
function data_to_csv($data, $headers = TRUE, $filename= "")
{
    if ( ! is_array($data))
    {
        show_error('invalid Data provided');
    }

    $array = array();

    if ($headers)
    {
        $array[] = array_keys($data[0]);
    }
    foreach ($data as $row)
    {
        $line = array();
        foreach ($row as $item)
        {
            $line[] = $item;
        }
        $array[] = $line;
    }
        header("Content-type: application/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename".".csv\"");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");

        $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        foreach ($array as $array) {
            fputcsv($handle, $array);
        }
            fclose($handle);
        exit;
}
```

Comment: How can i export multiple tables data into one csv file ?

Comment: It depend on your requirement one cannot say anything without knowing the exact requirements

Comment: Basically i want to export data of two html table in csv file one below other

Answer (score 0):

controller

```
    $result = $this->registration_model->exportToCsv();
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"application".".csv\"");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w');
   fputcsv($handle, array('Sr No.', 'Apply for', 'Name', 'mobile', 'email_id', 'work_experinece', 'pan', 'refrence', 'pro_img1', 'pro_img2', 'created_at'));
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach ($result as $data) {
                        fputcsv($handle, array($i, $data["apply_for"], $data["full_name"], $data["mobile"], $data["email_id"], $data["work_experinece"], $data["pan"], $data["refrence"], $data["pro_img1"], $data["pro_img2"], $data["created_at"]));
                        $i++;
                    }
                        fclose($handle);
                    exit;
```

Model

```
$this->db->select("apply_for,full_name,mobile,address,email_id,work_experinece,pan,refrence,pro_img1,pro_img2,created_at");
$this->db->order_by("app_id", "DESC");
$this->db->from("tablename"); 
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a line to [Abdul Manan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4391210/abdul-manan)'s answer to deal with UTF-8 characters :

```
       foreach ($array as $array) {
        fputs($handle, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));
        fputcsv($handle, $array);
    }
```